# UIView transitionFromView not animating in container

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, transition

I'm using UIView transitionFromView to flip between two views. I'm currently doing the following in a UIView subclass:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"]];

imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);

UIView *detailView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:imgView.frame];
detailView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

detailView.frame = imgView.frame;

[self addSubview:imgView];

[UIView transitionFromView:imgView toView:detailView duration:1.0 
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                completion:^(BOOL finished){

                }
 ];
```

This works as expected. The transition performs as it should. The issue is that I need the transition to take place in a subview of the view that the previous code is contained within. So, I put everything in a container and try to animate that:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"]];

imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);

UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500)];
UIView *detailView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:imgView.frame];
detailView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

detailView.frame = imgView.frame;

[container addSubview:imgView];

[self addSubview:container];

[UIView transitionFromView:imgView toView:detailView duration:1.0 
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                completion:^(BOOL finished){

                }
 ];
```

But in this case, the animation doesn't run. Instead, I only see the final result without the transition. Can anyone help me figure out how the two cases differ?

The same problem is described here, but I don't feel the existing 'solution' is sufficient to fully describe this behavior.
[Transition behavior using transitionFromView and transitionWithView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602434/transition-behavior-using-transitionfromview-and-transitionwithview)

Answer (score 1):

Consider delaying the animation to another run loop, using dispatch_after and performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:

or use [CATransaction flush] after you add the subviews

More info at http://andrewmarinov.com/working-with-uiviews-transition-animations/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the first one works, but this is not the correct way to use this method.  The view being transitioned away from will be removed from the hierarchy and the view being transitioned to will be added as part of the animation.  So skip adding detailView (or use the [UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews) option.

Comment: Changed the question to reflect that -- I've noticed that it doesn't make a difference one way or another...

Comment: That is strange, because I do the exact same thing and it works just fine.  The only difference is that I keep a reference active to both of the views so that I can switch back.  So the only other thing I can recommend is keeping an iVar reference to each view.  You aren't doing anything else after this block of code are you?

Comment: Nope. The transition is the last thing. The completion block is empty as well. I changed my container and subviews to strong iVars, and still get the same result.