# Flip animate UIVIEW only

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewanimation

```
code:
        [UIView transitionFromView:vwOne toView:vwTwo
            duration:1.0
            options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
            completion:NULL]
```

I created two views and made IBOutlet connection. I tried a simple flip animation.what i tried is flip animate UIView only.but entire VIEW CONTROLLER is animating.

Comment: may be this link hope with you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602434/transition-behavior-using-transitionfromview-and-transitionwithview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I taken the code for you from [here](http://andrewmarinov.com/working-with-uiviews-transition-animations/), if you need more reference please refer that link

```
UIView *fromView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,  containerView.frame.size.width, containerView.frame.size.height)];
fromView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
UIView *toView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, containerView.frame.size.width, containerView.frame.size.height)];
toView.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
[containerView addSubview:fromView];

[CATransaction flush];

[UIView transitionFromView:fromView toView:toView duration:0.4f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:NULL];
```